# Obtaining deepest file path with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, path

Does anyone have a brilliant idea how to obtain the elements with the deepest path from an array with file paths? If this sounds weird, imagine the following array:

```
/a/b
/a
/1/2/3/4
/1/2
/1/2/3/5
/a/b/c/d/e
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
/1/2/3/4
/1/2/3/5
/a/b/c/d/e
```

Wondering what the fastest method is without having to iterate over the whole array over and over again. Language is PHP (5.2).

Comment: What is your criteria for "deepest path", when the results you want to obtain have different depths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your clarifications, here's a function that would do it. It keeps an array of the "deepest paths" found and compares each path against it. The best-case scenario is O(n) (if all paths are subpaths of the largest one) and worst-case scenario is O(n<sup>2</sup>) (if all paths are completely distinct).

Note that `continue 2` means "continue on the outer loop".

```
<?php

function getDeepestPaths($array)
{
    $deepestPaths = array();
    foreach ($array as $path)
    {
        $pathLength = strlen($path);
        // look for all the paths we consider the longest
        // (note how we're using references to the array members)
        foreach ($deepestPaths as &$deepPath)
        {
            $deepPathLength = strlen($deepPath);
            // if $path is prefixed by $deepPath, this means that $path is
            // deeper, so we replace $deepPath with $path
            if (substr($path, 0, $deepPathLength) == $deepPath)
            {
                $deepPath = $path;
                continue 2;
            }
            // otherwise, if $deepPath is prefixed by $path, this means that
            // $path is shallower; so we should stop looking
            else if (substr($deepPath, 0, $pathLength) == $path)
            {
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        // $path matches nothing currently in $deepestPaths, so we should
        // add it to the array
        $deepestPaths[] = $path;
    }
    return $deepestPaths;
}

$paths = array('/a/b', '/a', '/1/2/3/4', '/1/2', '/1/2/3/5', '/a/b/c/d/e');
print_r(getDeepestPaths($paths));

?>
```

If your folder names don't end with slashes, you'll want to do an additional check in the two `if`s: that the character next to the prefix in the deeper path is a slash, because otherwise a path like `/foo/bar` will be seen as a "deeper path" than `/foo/b` (and will replace it).

```
if (substr($path, 0, $deepPathLength) == $deepPath && $path[$deepPathLength] == '/')
if (substr($deepPath, 0, $path) == $path && $deepPath[$path] == '/')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$aPathes = array(
    '/a/b',
    '/a',
    '/1/2/3/4',
    '/1/2',
    '/1/2/3/5',
    '/a/b/c/d/e'
);

function getDepth($sPath) {
    return substr_count($sPath, '/');
}
$aPathDepths = array_map('getDepth', $aPathes);
arsort($aPathDepths);
foreach ($aPathDepths as $iKey => $iDepth) {
    echo $aPathes[$iKey] . "\n";
}
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/7RjU2).

=== UPDATE ===

```
$aUsed = array();
foreach ($aPathes as $sPath) {
    foreach ($aUsed as $iIndex => $sUsed) {
        if (substr($sUsed, 0, strlen($sPath)) == $sPath || substr($sPath, 0, strlen($sUsed)) == $sUsed) {
            if (strlen($sUsed) < strlen($sPath)) {
                array_splice($aUsed, $iIndex, 1);
                $aUsed[] = $sPath;
            }
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $aUsed[] = $sPath;
}
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/jxR9w).

Comment: I don't want to find the deepest or nth deepest path in general, but throw away paths that are already included in other paths. See my example to understand what I am after. The reason is that I need to upload files over a slow FTP connection and have to create the paths before. If I create the path /some/very/deep/path there is no need to check for /some/very or /some because they are guaranteed to be there if /some/very/deep/path is. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the "spelling" is always the same (ie: "/a/b c/d" vs. /a/b\ /c/d) then you should be able to do some simple string comparation to see if one of the strings is fully contained within the other. If that is true discard the string.
Note that you will need to compare in both directions.